# DDD value object composite identifier

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities, value-objects

I was trying to understand DDD value objects and entities, and have a minor doubt in that. I've read in a lot of articles that value objects does not have identity. I wanted clarity on whether that the identity referred here is a single attribute or a any composite attributes.

Lets say I have an inventory management service which has a business transaction called "Inventory Adjustment", what it does is simply adjusts the quantity of items at your warehouse. You can create an adjustment with multiple line items, each line item will have an ItemID and Quantity fields.

Note: Lets assume that an item can occur only once in an adjustment, meaning an adjustment cannot have multiple line items with same Item ID.

The user can edit an adjustment line item, delete line items and add new line items as well.

In this context, is adjustmentLineItem a value object OR an entity inside adjustment root aggregate?

1. The confusion I have is when we say VOs should not have an identity, does that mean it should not have an ID field or a composite identity as well. Because in my case, I would not need an ID field for the line item object, the AdjustmentID + ItemID serves as an identifier for me.
2. Also, is it fine to have the parent entity identifier inside a VO (like adjustmentID)?
3. Not related to this context, in general what is the reason why VOs should not have identities?

NOTE: I am relatively new to DDD and my understandings might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between identifier and identity.

An **identifier** is a *value* that identify something, is what an entity use to track its **identity**.

The **identity** instead is what tells you that an entity is different from another one, you can use a number to do it (like in case of sql db sequences) or some UUID, or basically use a *value* that acts as an **identifier**

Difference between value objects and entities reside in the identity of the latter.

If we have an entity, let's say a Person, and we do a change (mutate) to it (eg. change name), it still remain the same entity (a person changing name still remain the same person). That is not true for value objects, if we have an Address and we change its street it is a different Address.

When we reify this abstraction into code, we need something to track the **identity** of an entity, to be able to check and confront it with another one. In these cases we add a *value* in the entity that acts as an **identifier**, something that we know will stay the same for the entire lifecycle of the entity.

So the **identifier** can be seen as a value and it can be treat as such.

Then going back to the questions:

1. It seems to me that in your case the `InventoryAdjustment` is the entity (it has its own identity), and it contains the list of `AdjustmentLineItem` that could be seen as a value, containing the `ItemId` that is also a value.
2. `AdjustmentLineItem` is a VO itself
3. Code to work with things not having an identity is simpler as they can easily be immutable, avoiding a lot of issues (you can look for the immutability topic to understand them, or [there's this famous talk about Values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM))

A final note about this rule:

> Lets assume that an item can occur only once in an adjustment

This enforce the fact that the `InventoryAdjustment` is an entity, and this rule is one of its *invariants*.
The `InventoryAdjustment` has a value in it being a `List<AdjustmentLineItem>`, and could check the rule when someone try to mutate it. When doing domain models, the access for editing purposes to the state of the entity should be disallowed, no setter methods and make impossible for external code of the `InventoryAdjustment` to do things like:

```
inventoryAdjustment.getAdjustmentLineItemList().add(anAdjustmentLineItem)
```

but rather expose methods to do mutation, and internally check invariants:

```
inventoryAdjustment.addAdjustmentLineItem(anAdjustmentLineItem)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It cleared some doubts. 1 question, if adjustmentLineItem is considered a VO.. it has the attributes AdjustmentID (the parent ref) and ItemID. Now this composite key is an identifier for that VO right? Shouldn't VO not have an identifier?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have some specific use case for having the AdjustmentID to be in the AdjustmentLineItem, I would make the InventoryAdjustment to contain the list of AdjustmentLineItem, and they don't know who is containing them

Comment: Saying this because as I see it to read the AdjustmentLineItem you need to pass through the InventoryAdjustment, so the id would already be there